# Nested findByTestId - React testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a situation where I want to check if particular element rendered inside particular div in my component:

```
import { render, within } from '@testing-library/react';

it('', async () => {
   const { findByTestId } = render(...);

   const wrapper = findByTestId('wrapper');

   const nestedDiv = within(wrapper).findByText('abc');
                   //        ^^^^^ error - value must be HTMLElement not object
});
```

[image]

Looking for help how to do it thanks

Comment: `findBy` queries need to be awaited. Change to `getByTestId` and it will work.